# Not able to execute a .sh file: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I wanted to execute a shell script:

```
-rwxr-x--x 1 root root   17234 Jun  6 18:31 create_mgw_3shelf_6xIPNI1P.sh
```

I tried to do a standard procedure, but I got this error:

```
./create_mgw_3shelf_6xIPNI1P.sh 
localhost 389 -l /opt/fews/sessions/AMGWM19/log/2013-06-06-143637_CLA-0 
DEBUG   cd/etc/opt/ldapfiles/ldif_in ;
./create_mgw_3shelf_6xIPNI1P.sh 
localhost 389 -l /opt/fews/sessions/AMGWM19/log/2013-06-06-143637_CLA-0
**ERROR  sh: ./create_mgw_3shelf_6xIPNI1P.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory**
```

What does it mean? I was doing this as the `root` user under the `root` group.

Does it mean that the file does not have the correct permission for the `root` user?

Answer (score 354):

This isn't a permission issue, you aren't getting a message about permissions

```
/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The script indicates that it must be executed by a shell located at `/bin/bash^M`. There is no such file: it's called `/bin/bash`.

The `^M` is a [carriage return character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return). Linux uses the [line feed character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_feed) to mark the end of a line, whereas Windows uses the two-character sequence CR LF. Your file has Windows line endings, which is confusing Linux.

Remove the spurious CR characters. You can do it with the following command:

```
sed -i -e 's/\r$//' create_mgw_3shelf_6xIPNI1P.sh
```

Comment: Or install and use the `dos2unix` program.

Comment: thank you for this, all other answers Ive found so far have not helped. This one did it!

Comment: doesn't have to be Windows, I got a similar message after copying a script from OS X to Ubuntu... dos2unix worked great in that case, whereas replacing '\r' with nothing would be worse, since there are no '\n' characters in the file.

Comment: @Michael macOS uses `\n` because it's Unix. The script was maybe from an earlier Mac OS version? You could run `sed -i -e 's/\r$/\n/' script.sh` in that case.

Comment: Open it in gedit and, do Save As, and select "Line Ending: Unix/Linux"

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. This really saved my time...!

Comment: In SciTE editor, to display characters:"View""End of Line" . To change the End of line character "Options","Line End Characters", then choose "LF". Now you can replace all the wrong "CR" by "LF" using "Options""Convert Line End Characters"

Comment: You can use the button on the bottom right in VS-Code to switch between CRLF (windows, dos) and LF (unix).

Comment: Just to share, this command works fine in Linux - In MacOS (El Capitan) does not work - practically all remain without the expected change

Comment: @ManuelJordan This is Ask Ubuntu, so I gave a command that works on Ubuntu, and more generally on Linux (including BusyBox). On other Unix-like systems you can use (for example) `perl -i -pe 's/\r$//' …` . On systems that don't recognize `\r` to mean a carriage return, the command I posted might error out of might remove `r` or `\r` (the two-character sequence backslash, lowercase R) at the end of lines. Recent macOS (at least Big Sur) does interpret `\r` as CR though.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - it was just an observation. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 49):

In vim you could also use `:set ff=unix` and then save the file, or `:set ff=dos` to get DOS formatting again.

Comment: this one did it for me, thx

Answer (score 45):

Your file has **DOS/Windows style line endings (CR LF)**, but on Unix-like systems only the **LF** control character is used as line break.

The additional [**CR** control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) is shown encoded as `^M` in your output. You can also see it when you run `cat -A create_mgw_3shelf_6xIPNI1P.sh`.

To convert the line endings from DOS/Windows style to Unix style, there's a tool called `dos2unix`. You install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

Then you can simply convert files' line endings in both ways using

```
dos2unix FILENAME
unix2dos FILENAME
```

In your case, simply run this command below and the script file will be converted in-place:

```
dos2unix create_mgw_3shelf_6xIPNI1P.sh
```

After that Bash should be able to interpret the file correctly.

Comment: Thanks, dos2unix is also available for macOS via brew.

Answer (score 18):

The Problem ist you edit with Dos!

open your file with vi
then set unix with:

```
:set ff=unix
:wq
```

and it all fine

Answer (score 6):

As explained in the other answers, this is a format issue. So, the answer is to change the format from DOS to Unix style line endings. This is yet another simple way to fix your file 'in place'

```
fromdos file
```

It's available in package `tofrodos`:

```
sudo apt-get install tofrodos
```

Answer (score 5):

Do `vi <your script>`.

then `:set list`; it will display any of the special characters in your script.

then replace the character:

`:%s/^M//gc`           [to type `^M` press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>]

Comment: See above answer about using :fileformat which is IMHO better for handling this than global substitution
Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609779/how-can-i-configure-bash-to-handle-crlf-shell-scripts/14610541 for ideas on how to handle automatically

Comment: I did `:set list` but say no special characters.  Just a `$` at the end of every line.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use gedit to remove the unwanted characters.
Under the File menu select Save As and set the line end type unix/Linux.

Comment: +1 for this because it helped me with MacOS line endings.

Answer (score 0):

I had developed the bash script on a Mac, so the first line of the script was

```
#!/opt/homebrew/bin/bash
```

When I tried to run it on ubuntu, I got the **bad-interpreter** issue. I changed the first line to

```
/usr/bin/bash
```

This change worked on ubuntu **which bash** command on ubuntu to find the path of bash.