# sed '/^$/d' and grep -Ev '^$' failed to remove blank lines

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, sed

I have such a file with multiple blank lines in vscode

```
$ tail -n 20 draft3.py
            hi = len(a)  

        if lo < 0:
            raise ValueError('low must be non-negative')

        if lo == hi: 
            return None 

        mid = (lo + hi) // 2

        if x == a[mid]:
            return x
        if x > a[mid]:

            lo = mid + 1
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
        if x < a[mid]:

            hi = mid
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
```

Tried multiple methods to remove the blank lines

`grep -v -e '^$' failed

```
$ tail -n 20 draft3.py | grep -v -e '^$'
            hi = len(a)  
        if lo < 0:
            raise ValueError('low must be non-negative')
        if lo == hi: 
            return None 
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2

        if x == a[mid]:
            return x
        if x > a[mid]:

            lo = mid + 1
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
        if x < a[mid]:

            hi = mid
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
```

`grep -Ev "^$" failed

```
$ tail -n 20 draft3.py | grep -Ev "^$" 
            hi = len(a)  
        if lo < 0:
            raise ValueError('low must be non-negative')
        if lo == hi: 
            return None 
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2

        if x == a[mid]:
            return x
        if x > a[mid]:

            lo = mid + 1
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
        if x < a[mid]:

            hi = mid
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
```

`sed '/^$/d' failed

```
$ tail -n 20 draft3.py | sed '/^$/d'
            hi = len(a)  
        if lo < 0:
            raise ValueError('low must be non-negative')
        if lo == hi: 
            return None 
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2

        if x == a[mid]:
            return x
        if x > a[mid]:

            lo = mid + 1
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
        if x < a[mid]:

            hi = mid
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
```

What's the problem? How could remove the blank lines?

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you want to remove not only empty lines, but also lines with only whitespace characters. For that, use:

```bsh
sed '/^\s*$/d'   # or respectively
grep -v '^\s*$'
```

The `sed` expression `d`eletes every line with any number (`*`) of whitespace characters (`\s`) in it. `grep -v` outputs any line which does not match the expression.

#### Example usage

```bsh
$ sed '/^\s*$/d' <draft3.py 
            hi = len(a)  
        if lo < 0:
            raise ValueError('low must be non-negative')
        if lo == hi: 
            return None 
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if x == a[mid]:
            return x
        if x > a[mid]:
            lo = mid + 1
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
        if x < a[mid]:
            hi = mid
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
```

Answer (score 3):

`grep -v '^$'` will remove **empty** lines. But what if we have spaces or tabs in some lines ? For example I added 3 spaces to parts of your text, and if we do `cat -A` we will see that it shows line terminator `$`, but it will be offset.

```
$
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2$
   $
        if x == a[mid]:$
            return x$
        if x > a[mid]:$
```

The second line there has 3 spaces, first one doesn't. So we also want to use `[[:blank:]]` character class to account for those as well:

```
$ grep -v '^[[:blank:]]*$' text.txt
           hi = len(a)  
        if lo < 0:
            raise ValueError('low must be non-negative')
        if lo == hi: 
            return None 
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if x == a[mid]:
            return x
        if x > a[mid]:
            lo = mid + 1
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
        if x < a[mid]:
            hi = mid
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
```

Now you should see that the line with 3 added spaces is gone. The `*` signifies zero or more repetitions of the characters, so the pattern `^[[:blank:]]*$` also implies `^$` when there are zero whitespace or tab characters on the line. So this pattern handles both truly empty and seemingly empty lines. It also applies exactly the same to `grep` or `sed`, because we're using basic regex expressions and `[[:blank:]]` is one of the [POSIX character classes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html), so it is portable.

---

We could also do something like this in python but without regex patterns:

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys; print("\n".join([ l.rstrip() for l in sys.stdin if l.strip().split() ]))'  < text.txt
           hi = len(a)
        if lo < 0:
            raise ValueError('low must be non-negative')
        if lo == hi:
            return None
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if x == a[mid]:
            return x
        if x > a[mid]:
            lo = mid + 1
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
        if x < a[mid]:
            hi = mid
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
```

Why does this work ? Because `.split()` on a string will split at whitespaces to extract non-whitespace tokens. If a line contains only spaces, the resulting list from `.split()` will be empty.

---

As noted by ilkkachu in the comments, the issue can also occur if you use CRLF line endings ( used in DOS/Windows text files). It is easy to see if the file uses CRLF line endings via `cat -A`, they will be marked as `^M`. For example,

```
$ printf 'hello\n\r\nWorld\n   \r\ntest\n\nnewtest\n' | cat -A
hello$
^M$
World$
   ^M$
test$
$
newtest$
```

One thing that could be done to account for carriage return is this:

```
$ printf 'hello\n\r\nWorld\n   \ntest\n\nnewtest\n' | sed '/^[[:blank:]]*\r*$/d'
hello
World
test
newtest
```

It may be simpler to first use a `dos2unix` utility designed specifically for converting DOS files to Unix files, and then use `sed` and `grep`. See [ByteCommander's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/861053/295286) that shows example of how to do that.

Comment: "regular" whitespace like spaces could do that, or they might have CRLF line endings

Comment: @ilkkachu Good point, thank you. I've edited to account for CRLF as well

Comment: oh, I just noticed you used `[:blank:]` and not `[:space:]`. The latter would match the CR too.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
perl -p  -e 's/^[:blank:]*$//g' inputfile | sed '/^$/d'
```

and you will have

```
tail -n 20 draft3.py
            hi = len(a)
        if lo < 0:
            raise ValueError('low must be non-negative')
        if lo == hi:
            return None
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        if x == a[mid]:
            return x
        if x > a[mid]:
            lo = mid + 1
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
        if x < a[mid]:
            hi = mid
            return self.bi_search(a, x, lo, hi)
```

Only with sed is

```
sed -r 's/^[[:space:]]*$//g' inputfile | sed '/^$/d'
```

Answer (score 0):

This grep command works and even accounts for dos carriage returns, blank/empty lines, and blank lines that contain empty spaces and/or tabs:

```
grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$'
```