# ./docker-build.sh: ./mvnw: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, 22.04, shebang

I am using Ubuntu 22.04

File `docker-build.sh`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$1" = "native" ];
then
  ./mvnw clean -Pnative spring-boot:build-image --projects book-service -DskipTests
else
  ./mvnw clean compile jib:dockerBuild --projects book-service
fi
```

or online link at https://github.com/ivangfr/springboot-kong-keycloak/blob/main/docker-build.sh

[image]

```bash
 ./docker-build.sh
```

error

```
./docker-build.sh: ./mvnw: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Your `./mvnw` script (rather than the `docker-build.sh` script itself) likely has DOS-style line endings. See for example [Not able to execute a .sh file: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304999/not-able-to-execute-a-sh-file-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter)